# Map multiple routes to 1 action in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I want to map multiple urls to 1 action, but I just want 1 route.

For eg.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SingleUser_Long",
    "Users/{username}",
    new { controller = "Users", action = "SingleUser" });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Users",
    "{username}",
    new { controller = "Users", action = "SingleUser" });
```

Is there a way I can put these 2 in 1? Its becomming tedious when I have to add more and I keep copy/paste duplicates, only to add "Users" infront of the url.

Comment: You want to add 'Users' infront of the url? Doesn't this automatically happen because your controller is named 'Users'?

Comment: Right now the Urls 'localhost/Users/1' and 'localhost/1' maps to SingleUser action. But as you can see, it required 2 MapRoute, is it possible to do in 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    routes.MapRoute("SingleUser", 
      "{controller}/{username}",
       new { controller = "Users", action = "SingleUser", 
                 controller = UrlParameter.Optional },
       new { controller = @"/(^\s*)|\bUsers\b"}
```

using constraint to restrict "{controller}" to be empty or "Users" only.(not sure the regular expression is right)